# Why the solution is more involved than needed?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, math-history

In Euclid's Elements the solution to the second problem/proposition is great but seems more complicated than needed. ([link to the page](https://books.google.ru/books?id=n2YLAQAAIAAJ&dq=euclid%20elements&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q=euclid%20elements&f=false))

Why not just take the length of $BC$ like it is done in the next proposition?

> From the point $A$ draw the straight line $AD$ equal to C

Comment: Because Prop.I.2 is proved using Prop.I.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done in the third proposition precisely because it was proved that it can be done in the second proposition.

Comment: Then what is the minimal allowed set of operations? Assuming a circle is drawn with a compass, we could take the length of a line with it. Then there's no need to prove it could be done.

Comment: @Hrisip That is *exactly* the point. No, we cannot “take the length of a line with it”, since no axiom tells us we can. And take into account the fact that the word “compass” is absent from the *Elements*.

Comment: Oh, right, I see. We operate only with shapes. And the fact that they are drawn is only for the purpose of demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

Proposition 1.1 says essentially that you can use your (modern) compasses to measure a line segment in one place and transfer it to another line. That needs to be proved, because all  Euclid's compasses do is draw circles with given center and radius. If you pick them up they collapse.

Comment: But to be clear, we still can't actually measure a line at this point. Because we can't place the line of the same length at any point and at any angle. And to be honest I can't see how that can be a prove, since we have two points E and F, which we don't know how to place geometrically(i.e. without actually drawing)(and if we knew how to continue a line we still don't know how long it should be, so it should be infinitely long).